# C# interface Doesn't allow member class to forfill requirements

Tags: c#, interface

Sorry if the title is not very descriptive. I didn't know how to describe this.

First, I created an interface like this:

```
public interface IUser {}
```

Then implemented it in several classes like this:

```
public class Student : IUser {}

public class Teacher : IUser {}
```

Then I created an Interface that required the first interface

```
public class IUsers
{
    List<IUser> Users {get; set;}
}
```

Then I created a Class that used the second interface, but used one of the Members of the first interface to for fill the contract.

```
public class Students : IUsers 
{
    List<Student> Users {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is the last one I wanted to constrain the list to just one implementation of the interface, but still need to maintain the interface for data compatibility. When I do this I get an error saying I'm not implementing the interface. I thought that since Student implemented the interface it would for fill the obligation, but it doesn't seem to. Is this correct or am I doing something else wrong

Comment: It is a standard type-safety violation.  If this could compile then code could use the interface to add an object to the list that implements IUser but is not a Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, to me the sample appears to indicate you would like to maintain separate implementations for your users, then return the desired implementation.

```
public interface IStudentFactory
{
     IUser Create();
}

public class StudentFactory
{
    public IUser Create() => new StudentContext();
}
```

Then based on your implementation inside your interface of IUser, you could connect to your data store to manage those types of user.

```
var context = new StudentFactory().Create())
var students = context.GetAllStudents();
context.Students.Add(new Student() { });
```

The approach I provided is under the notion that you want to be able to access this information about different types of users, persist, and manage.  Your example showed a primitive collection where you are adding, potentially handling other functionality, but I imagine you are working more towards something a bit more consistent.

I may be off the mark for your intent, but that is how I interpreted.

Comment: I think this is more what I was going for, Thanks!

Comment: @evilsushi I had a feeling you were trying to achieve the above, but didn't know exactly how to get there.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 8):

You need to say what *kind* of users your collection supports. Suppose your code were valid - then this would compile:

```
IUsers users = new Students();
// What would this do at execution time? It's not safe!
users.Users.Add(new Teacher());
```

After all, that's just adding a `Teacher` to a `List<IUser>`, right? But in `Students`, the `Users` property is a `List<Student>`, so that can't accept a teacher.

The best approach is probably to make your `IUsers` interface generic in the type of user it accepts:

```
public class IUsers<TUser> where TUser : IUser
{
    List<TUser> Users {get; set;}
}
```

Then your `Students` class would implement `IUsers<Student>`, and the property would be fine.

At that point, the problematic example at the top of the answer would fail to compile:

```
// This is fine
IUsers<Student> users = new Students();
// This won't compile, because users.Users is of type List<Student>, and you can't add
// a Teacher to that.
users.Users.Add(new Teacher());
```